# Modifying entry in django admin creates duplicate

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-admin

I am using the django admin to modify records in a table. The problem is that whenever I modify an entry, when I click save, instead of modifying that entry, the old one is not modified and a new entry containing the modified details is being added.

For example, if I have the following:

```
Aardvark | Orycteropus | Some description | aardvark | animals/images/aardvark.jpg
```

when I change the first field to `Aardvarkon`, I get the following:

```
Aardvark | Orycteropus | Some description | aardvark | animals/images/aardvark.jpg
Aardvarkon | Orycteropus | Some description | aardvark | animals/images/aardvark.jpg
```

I have the following django model:

```
def article_file_name(instance, filename):
    return ANIMAL_IMAGES_BASE_DIR[1:] + instance.ai_species_species_sanitized + '.jpg'

class ai_species(models.Model):
    ai_species_species = models.CharField('Species', max_length=100, primary_key=True, db_column='species')
    ai_species_genus = models.ForeignKey(ai_genera, max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, db_column='genus')
    ai_species_description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=65000, db_column='description')
    ai_species_species_sanitized = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, db_column='species_sanitized')
    image_url = models.ImageField(max_length=100, storage=OverwriteStorage(), validators=[validate_jpg_extension], upload_to=article_file_name)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Species'
        verbose_name = 'Animal species'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Animal species'
    def __unicode__(self): # Required, don't remove.
        return self.ai_species_species
```

And the following helpers:

```
def validate_jpg_extension(value):
    if not value.name.lower().endswith('.jpg') and not value.name.lower().endswith('.jpeg'):
        raise ValidationError(u'Invalid file format! Only jpg or jpeg files allowed!')

class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def get_available_name(self, name):
        # If the filename already exists, remove it.
        if self.exists(name):
            os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name))
        return name
```

This is the MySQL table schema for this table:

[image: Table schema]

This is a very counter-intuitive behavior and I haven't found any other occurrences of this online. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the culprit:

```
 ai_species_species = models.CharField('Species', max_length=100, primary_key=True, db_column='species')
```

Since you've defined the species as the primary key, any time you change this field in the admin it will create a new record (because there isn't already a record with that primary key).

FYI, primary keys aren't supposed to be things that change for a given record, since changing the primary key will invalidate every foreign key (`ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField`, and `ManyToManyField`) that refers to the record.

BTW, you don't need to be prefixing the field names with `ai_species_`; it's cluttering. Removing those prefixes would remove the need for the `db_column` parameters as well.